# Get the values of all input parameters in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a webapp that allows users to create custom input components. This is in the form of MUI Select and TextFields:

```
const CTextField = (
  <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" size="small" />
);

const CSelect = function(match) {
  match = match.substring(1, match.length - 1);
  const matches = match.split("/");
  let menus = [];
  matches.forEach(single => {
    menus.push(<MenuItem value={single}>{single}</MenuItem>);
  });
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Select>{menus}</Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

The issue I'm coming across is, how can I grab all the values placed or selected from the components. They're created by the end user, so there can be any number of them, and I'm trying to keep it in order with plain text.

What I think works is simply grabbing the raw data including html and stripping it away, then grabbing the values. But because I want this to be dynamic, that'd end up being slow the larger the text is. Is there an efficient method of grabbing all the raw text as well as the values of the input components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about how many elements you have - that's why `Array`s are there:

```js
const { useState } = React

const App = (props) => { 
  const [inputFieldsList, setInputFieldsList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Input field list:</h1>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const newVal = [...inputFieldsList, '']
          setInputFieldsList(newVal)
      }}>ADD INPUT FIELD</button>

      {inputFieldsList.map((item, i) => (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              const newList = [...inputFieldsList]
              newList[i] = e.target.value
              setInputFieldsList(newList)
              console.log(inputFieldsList)
            }}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useState` for storing the values of the input, and `onChange` function to set your state when a user types in the input.

```
const Hello = () => {

const[values, setValues] = useState({
                              input1: '',
                              input2: ''
                             });

const changeHandler = () => {
    setValues(
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
     );
}



 return (
           <>
                <input type="text" value={values.input1} name="input1" onChange={changeHandler} />
                <input type="text" value={values.input2} name="input2" onChange={changeHandler} />
            </>
        );


}
```

Comment: The issue with that is there isn't a set amount of inputs, is there a way to keep track of all of them in a single state?